# Android Studio: Set Text in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-view

I've recently picked up an Android Studio project I started a year ago in Kotlin.
It features three fragments that can be navigated through by a bottom navigation bar.

Now, to break my current issue down to a simple example that even doesn't work for me:
Given there's a the editText object `exercise` in `fragment_home.xml` and I want to call and alter it in `HomeFragment.kt`.
I checked every source of advice I could find from Google & Stackoverflow and came up with the following code in `HomeFragment.kt` (partially pre-coded by AndroidStudio):

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)

        view.exercise.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")
```

The last line stands for every object I tried to reach. I also tried onClickListening for buttons like so:

```
val btnNewExercise =  view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_new_exercise)
btnNewExercise.setOnClickListener {view

            Toast.makeText(view.context, "New exercise will be generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("Generated a new exercise")
        }
```

but nothing happens when I start the app/ hit the buttons - I seem to can't get through to the actual view's objects to access them. Even ran into NullPointerExceptions on my way to a solution.

I could supply the fragment and layout files if needed - just thought this way it might be easier at first.

If anybody could tell me where I'm wrong I'd be really grateful! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inflated the layout twice.

Remove this. You already inflated the layout using view binding in the  *FragmentHomeBinding.inflate...*  call

```
val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
```

and replace

```
view.exercise.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")
```

with (using binding

```
 binding.exercise.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")
```

then the last line on your onCreateView should be

```
   return binding.root
```

Note: You should have these class properties:

```
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

So it will look like this:

```
               //move your view model as a class property so it will be accessible by other class methods
                 private val homeViewModel =
                          ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

 
                 private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
                 private val binding get() = _binding!!//transform to immutable
            
                 override fun onCreateView(
                        inflater: LayoutInflater,
                        container: ViewGroup?,
                        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                    ): View? {

                        
                
                        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
                      
                       //use the immutable view binding property
                        binding.exercise.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")
            
                        return binding.root
                   }
```

For more info, read [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
Makes totally sense - inflating the layout twice is redundant and that's why I didn't adress the actual objects.

However, I'm facing a new issue now, that is ```Smart cast to 'FragmentHomeBinding' is impossible, because '_binding' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time``` when using `_binding.exercise.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")`.

Comment: I was able to get rid of this error by adding question marks like so `_binding?.exercise?.setText("This is an exceptionally hardcoded string")`  and in `return _binding?.root` but I'm not sure if that's used like intended.

Comment: As a workaround for buttons I had to use _!!_ in e.g. `val btnNewExercise : Button =  _binding!!.btnNewExercise`. Should it be like this?

And could anything have interfered with the navController in the `MainActivity.kt`?
I'm now stuck at ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.trampcompanion_btmnav.MainActivity@c8cbe7f does not have a NavController set on 2131231026```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MalteGe My bad. You need to transform _binding into immutable property by  `private val binding get() = _binding!!` and return it instead.   Pls see updated answer.

Comment: In referencing views, use the immutable viewbinding property like on your btn_new_exercise, it should be `binding.btnNewExercise.setOnClickListener{...  `

Comment: Thank you! I just updated all my code to your improved solution and there was no error left before compiling. Afterwards though, the app ran into an error in my `MainActivity.kt` at the line `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` 
in

`private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)`

Comment: The error message is `The error message is `Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.trampcompanion_btmnav.ui.home.HomeFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception'`

Already trying to tackle it but I'm not sure what to change in `MainActivity.kt`.
I read on similar topics, it could be due to naming of XMLs or objects in them like in `mobile_navigation.xml`or `fragment_home.xml`. I did change something recently there but it was just the labels, no id I seem to recall.

Comment: I think you can post a separate question for that (MainActivity.kt).

Comment: I was able to solve the other second error myself and the app finally works (again) :) 
Thank you for your previous assistance! Tell me if/ how I can buy you a coffee if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
  val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.exercise.text="This is an exceptionally hardcoded string"

        binding.btnNewExercise.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(view.context, "New exercise will be generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("Generated a new exercise")

        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I checked the other one first as I had to change less program code but I commited my changes to be able to easily check out the program's state from before and try your solution. I'll let you know if it worked once I'm having the time to test it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the view you made in the OnCreateView .